# Why are array strings separated by a comma?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to make a list from info the user enters.

```
   var todoArray = new Array();

document.getElementById("addButton").onclick = function(){

    var temp = document.getElementById("inputBox").value;
    var appendTemp = "<li><input type=\"checkbox\">" + temp + "</li>";

    todoArray.push(appendTemp);

    document.getElementById("todoListUL").innerHTML = todoArray;

    console.log(todoArray);

}
```

But when the list times show up, they all have a comma between them, JSFiddle link for imagery here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kaio37k/5k0mzypw/3/)

Why are they separated by this comma and how do I remove it?

Comment: Because that's how an array's `toString()` is implicitly called when you try to make an array a string - in `document.getElementById("todoListUL").innerHTML = todoArray;`

Comment: `todoArray.join('[use a character here or not]')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in this line:

```
document.getElementById("todoListUL").innerHTML = todoArray;
```

because the right member is converted to `string` and it is invoked internally the `join` method for `todoArray` array and default `delimiter` is `comma`.

Change it to

```
document.getElementById("todoListUL").innerHTML = todoArray.join("");
```

Comment: Thank you! This fixed it and helped me understand the issue. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

When you assign any value to the `.innerHTML` property of an element, the value is implicitly converted to a string and then parsed as HTML.  The default way that an array is converted to a string is via the `.join()` method, and the default array separator is a comma.

If you don't want anything, you can just call `.join()` yourself:

```
document.getElementById("todoListUL").innerHTML = todoArray.join("");
```